# How can the following pandas script be made more efficient?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have an excel sheet `G0.xlsx` which has 3 sheets in it `Winter`, `Summer`, `Rest`

Since the file has multiple contents, I am sharing the link of the file: [Link to the file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z_-wOJYF86WB0jbsN6PCwcyghhn_AEj0/view?usp=sharing)

I am trying to manipulate the data in all the 3 sheets in order to build one huge file for one entire year and the time must be of a 15min frequency (as it is in the file).

I also have the following conditions:

> Winter: 01.11 - 20.03
>
> Summer: 15.05 - 14.09
>
> Rest: 21.03 - 14.05 & 15.09 - 31.10

and based on these conditions, the final table must contain the values.

The below code works perfectly fine for me, but it takes a lot of time for generating the output. I want to know if this code can be made more time-efficient.

```
import pandas as pd
import holidays
import numpy as np
import functools

YEAR = 2020
seasons = ['Winter', 'Summer', 'Rest']

def get_holidays(year, country='DE', province=None):
    if province is not None:
        country_holidays = holidays.CountryHoliday(
            country, years=int(year), prov=province)
    else:
        country_holidays = holidays.CountryHoliday(
            country, years=int(year))
    country_holidays = list(country_holidays.keys())
    country_holidays = [d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for d in country_holidays]
    return country_holidays

def calculate_day(x):
    # get previous day for timestamp before hh:15
    if x.hour == 0 and x.minute < 15:
        return (x - pd.DateOffset(days=1)).day_name()
    return x.day_name()

def date_editing_df(df, holiday_list, year):
    year = str(year)
    weekdays = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']

    td = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'].astype(str))
    df1 = df.assign(Time=td.mask(td == pd.Timedelta(0),
                                 td + pd.Timedelta(1, 'd')), a=1)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'dates': pd.date_range(
        '01.01.'+year, '31.12.'+year), 'a': 1})

    df = df2.merge(df1, how='outer').drop('a', axis=1)
    df['dates'] = df['dates'].add(
        df.pop('Time')).dt.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')

    df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], dayfirst=True)
    df['day'] = df['dates'].apply(calculate_day)

    df['day'].replace(weekdays, 'Werktag', inplace=True)
    df['day'].replace(
        {'Saturday': 'Samstag', 'Sunday': 'Sonntag'}, inplace=True)

    holiday_list = pd.to_datetime(holiday_list).tolist()
    comp = [(df['dates'] > h) & (df['dates'] <= h +
                                 pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=1))
            for h in holiday_list]
    # join all mask by logical or
    mask = np.logical_or.reduce(comp)

    df['day'] = np.where(mask, 'Sonntag', df['day'])
    df['Final'] = df.lookup(df.index, df['day'])
    df.drop(['Samstag', 'Sonntag', 'Werktag'], axis=1, inplace=True)
    return df

for season in seasons:
    df = pd.read_excel('G0.xlsx', header=0, sheet_name=seasons)

w_df = df['Winter']
s_df = df['Summer']
r_df = df['Rest']

h_list = get_holidays(YEAR)

w_df = date_editing_df(w_df, h_list, YEAR)
s_df = date_editing_df(s_df, h_list, YEAR)
r_df = date_editing_df(r_df, h_list, YEAR)

w_df.rename(columns={'Final': 'winter'}, inplace=True)
s_df.rename(columns={'Final': 'summer'}, inplace=True)
r_df.rename(columns={'Final': 'rest'}, inplace=True)

all_dfs = [w_df, s_df, r_df]
final_df = functools.reduce(
    lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on='dates'), all_dfs)


d = pd.to_datetime(final_df['dates'].dt.strftime('%m-%d-' + str(YEAR)))
m1 = d.between(
    str(YEAR)+'-11-01', str(YEAR)+'-12-31') | d.between(str(YEAR)+'-01-01',
                                              str(YEAR)+'-03-20')
m2 = d.between(str(YEAR)+'-05-15', str(YEAR)+'-09-14')
final_df['Season'] = np.select(
    [m1, m2],
    ['winter', 'summer'],
    default='rest'
)
final_df['values'] = final_df.lookup(
    final_df.index,
    final_df['Season']
)
final_df = final_df[['dates', 'values']]
```